# PHP: get data from XML string

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I have a simple problem getting data from an eBay API string. I want to format numbers to 2 digits 8.0 > 8.00

This works fine

```
echo $price;  // output: 8.0
```

But...

```
echo number_format($price, 2);  // output:   (nothing)
```

A var_dump tells me why...

```
var_dump($price);  
// output: object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["currencyId"]=> string(3) "USD" } [0]=> string(3) "8.0" }
```

How do I get the 8.0 into a 8.00 (I know I can use REGEX but it feels like not the proper way)

And while we are here, how I can get the 'USD' ?

PS: the API call used is findCompletedItems - and strangely to me, the XML response has no visible USD at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var_dump gives you an object of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which has a [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method which returns the text content that is directly in the element so `echo $price;` will result in `8.0`

The `USD` is part of the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) which returns an object of type SimpleXMLElement.

You can get the price and the currency casting it to a `(string)`

```
$priceAsString = (string)$price;
$currencyIdAsString = (string)$price->attributes()->currencyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing in a string, you're passing in an object of class `SimpleXMLElement`. The easiest you can do is cast it to a string before passing it to number_format using `(string)$price`

Comment: Thanks. It works exactly the way I wanted. However, I don't really understand why I can parse the '8.0' and not the 'USD'.